# How to get an url attribute from a namespaced XML source with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, rss-reader

I am trying to show a Rss feed in Nuxt with Axios.

I can get:

- title
- link
- description

It is working but for the images which are in:

> <media:content url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/00e5cfa7_mv2.jpg" medium="image >

I can't find the way to access it.

Here is my axios:

```html
<script>
  asyncData ({params}, callback) {
    axios.get("https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/rss.xml" )
      .then((res) => {
        var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString
        var xml = res.data
        parseString(xml, (message, xmlres) => {
          callback(null,{ data: xmlres.rss.channel[0].item})
        })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        callback({ statusCode: 404, message: 'error' })
      })
  },
</script>
```

and in my template:

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
      <a :href="item.link">
        {{item.title}}
        {{item.description}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

My rss.xml is like this :

```xml
<item>
    <title>Yanii Models | Ben and Ezra</title>
    <link>https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra</link>
    <guid>https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra</guid>
    <description>Petit Bâteau</description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 16 Jul 2021 16:27:00 GMT</pubDate>
    <media:content url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg" medium="image"/>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg"/>
</item>
```

Comment: The url `https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/00e5cfa7_mv2.jpg` looks to be protected actually.

Comment: Hello Kissu sorry i cut it coz it was long one here is the full url : https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg

Comment: So, what is your actual issue? You don't know how to parse it properly into something readable or how to display an image in Nuxt?

Comment: My actual issue is how to parse it properly for get the url of the image inside : <media:content url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b340f09c3fdcc1f92e83_b79a66_496ce9215d6d4614adb3b64d6af790ef_mv2.jpg" medium="image"/>

Comment: We could make this with regex but there is probably a simpler way. Do you have a JSON at some point? Never really worked with XML before. What is `parseString` giving you?

Comment: I dont have a JSON at some point i think Kissu i use 'xml2js' and i followed a tutorial for use it im kind of lost with RSS feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the RSS feed:

1. [`@nuxtjs/axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/axios) is commonly used with Nuxt, which provides access to `axios` via the `$axios` context property (1st argument for `asyncData`). There's no need to import it in your component.
2. The `asyncData()` `callback` parameter is deprecated. Use `async`/`await` instead.
3. Use the [`Promise`-based `xml2js` parser API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#promise-usage) for more succinct code.
4. `xml2js` seems to wrap all propertries in an array, so you'll have to unwrap it (or index into it, which would be inconvenient to me).
5. There is no `item.id` property, but there's `item.guid`. Use that for the `v-for` item key.
6. The image URL is stored in `media:content.$.url` of each item. You could bind that URL to `<img>.src`.

```html
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $axios 1️⃣, params }, /* callback 2️⃣ */) {
    const res = await $axios.get("https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/rss.xml")
    const xmlres = await parseStringPromise(res.data) 3️⃣
    
    4️⃣
    const data = xmlres.rss.channel[0].item.map(item => {
      const newEntries = Object.entries(item).map(([key,val]) => [key, val[0]])
      return Object.fromEntries(newEntries)
    })

    return { data }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in data" :key="item.guid"> 5️⃣
      ...
      <img :src="item['media:content'].$.url"> 6️⃣
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-parse-rss-feed?file=pages%2Findex.vue)

Answer (score 1):

I know that tony already got an accepted answer but here is my approach on this one, I thought it may still be relevant to share.

I used [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) and achieved to have the following JSON from your xml with the `ignoreAttributes: false` option (because we needed your `url` attribute).

```json
{
  "title": "Yanii Models | Ben and Ezra",
  "link": "https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra",
  "guid": "https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra",
  "description": "Petit Bâteau",
  "pubDate": "Fri, 16 Jul 2021 16:27:00 GMT",
  "media:content": {
    "@_url": "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg",
    "@_medium": "image"
  },
  "media:thumbnail": {
    "@_url": "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg"
  }
}
```

Here is the whole code to integrate a basic page

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ jsonObj.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ jsonObj.description }}</p>
    <a :href="jsonObj.link">Link</a>

    <br />
    <img :src="jsonObj['media:thumbnail']['@_url']" alt="thumbnail image" />
    <br />
    <img :src="jsonObj['media:content']['@_url']" alt="full image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import parser from 'fast-xml-parser'

export default {
  asyncData() {
    const xml = `<item>
      <title>Yanii Models | Ben and Ezra</title>
      <link>https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra</link>
      <guid>https://yaniimodels.webflow.io/categories/ben-and-ezra</guid>
      <description>Petit Bâteau</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 16 Jul 2021 16:27:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <media:content url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg" medium="image"/>
      <media:thumbnail url="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60f1911b212fd90baa99ee92/60f1b23cf09c3f73a4f92a1b_b79a66_8fa332a4dea94558b5f1e97200e5cfa7_mv2.jpg"/>
      </item>`
    const jsonObj = parser.parse(xml, { ignoreAttributes: false }).item
    return { jsonObj }
  },
}
</script>
```

And here is how it looks
[image]